# Converting hibernate entity to JSON: oblectId instead of whole object

Tags: java, json, hibernate

Project has two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "city_id", nullable = true)
private City city;
...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class City {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
private String name;
...
}
```

Cutomer entity to JSON using Gson or Jackson converts as

```
{
"id":1,
"city":{"id":1, "name":"New York"}
}
```

I want it is converts as

```
{
"id":1,
"city_id":1
}
```

How I can do that via gson or jackson?

Comment: you should use a custom Serializer to achieve this. @Satmurat

Comment: Please Check my Answer at this Link >[How to use Customize Serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592831/should-serialization-logic-be-in-the-entity-or-other-class/35593831#35593831)

Comment: @VikrantKashyap, writing serializer for each entity is not nice.

Answer (score 0):

This question might be helpful to you.

[Gson: How to exclude specific fields from Serialization without annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802887/gson-how-to-exclude-specific-fields-from-serialization-without-annotations)

I don't know if there is a direct way to accomplish this, but there are indirect ways in which it can be done. For instance, you could mark `private City city` as `transient`, and then you could expose another field called `city_id` that would simply be the city id. It would look something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id", nullable = true)
    private transient City city;

    private int city_id;
    ...
}
```