# Can I use a JSONArray instead of creating a data model?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm relatively new to Java programming within Android so I have a basic question for my understanding about how should I deal with incoming JSON data from my server.

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, completeURL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            try {

                // just use this JSONArray?

            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    }, ...
```

I know about the [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) Library but therefore I have to create a data model. My JSON data is relatively complex so that would be a little bit of effort.

Would it be bad (and why?) when I just use the created JSONArray and pass it around the activities?

Comment: now days there is lots of classes which provide JSON parsing like Gson,volley, retrofit, ObjectMapper that makes easy Json parshing, instead of manual parsing with help of jsonArray and jsonObject is quite tricky and cause error. i would refer Gson.

Comment: Copy your json array into this site http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/. It will generate JAVA POJO class for you. Then use GSON for parsing

Comment: You could pass your `JSONArray` between you activities and render data or whatever your requirement is. But know that you have parse/loop the array everytime you need some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you can take JSON as a response and pick the required fields / pass it to other activities.

It is always recommended to keep your serialization and business logic separate. If you move around the activities with the JSON object, then you are mixing up both of them.

So, as and when your project progresses and you have stable contract with the API server, you can consider introducing POJO classes. There are lot of libraries like Jackson, Gson etc which help you in converting JSON <==> POJO.

Ref: [Should serialization logic be in the entity or other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592831/should-serialization-logic-be-in-the-entity-or-other-class)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the variable **response** check my below snippet of code.

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET, completeURL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            try {
                    // Parsing json array response
                    // loop through each json object


                     for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

              }
        }, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create a data model with GSON and I have to say it was the best decision.

Everyone who is thinking about that. Go for it!